# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier problem keeps coming up on reload

Tags: ajaxform

I keep getting the same error in console.log

I cannot see the error

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'index.php',
   method: 'POST',
   data: {
        search: 1,
        q: query
   },
   success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
   }
   datatype: 'text'
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe cause you've forgot `,` before `datatype`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it's all ok, but you've forgot `,` between `success` and `datatype`(this solves your first issue), and at the end of `$.ajax` use `})` instead of `}}`(this solves your next issue):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'index.php',
   method: 'POST',
   data: {
        search: 1,
        q: query
   },
   success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
   },                    // here
   datatype: 'text'   
})                       // and here
```

Now it should work properly.